# How to define propertyMissing() in a FactoryBuilderSupport without losing the Script delegate

Tags: groovy, dsl

I am trying to define a DSL for building a domain specific query.  The DSL is implemented using FactoryBuilderSupport so it looks something like below (abbreviated):

```
class QueryBuilder extends FactoryBuilderSupport {
   {
     registerFactory('query', new QueryFactory())
     registerFactory('match', new QueryMatchFactory())
     registerFactory('obj', new ObjFactory())
   }
   def propertyMissing(String name) {
     //give user meaningful message about the bad 'name' here
   }
}
```

This works fine if I just run it as a groovy script (in IntelliJ or whatever)  The script looks something like below:

```
def bldr = new QueryBuilder()

def queryBuilder = bldr.query() {
  match {
    obj {
      //More stuff in here
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I really want is to get the script from a web interface and run it.  So my first shot at this is to create a Delegating script.  For whatever reason I had to say delegate.query() rather than just query or it ignores my delegate.  This is contradictory to the documentation I read.

```
class DslEvaluator {

 def evaluateDsl (dsl) {
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder()
    def compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration()
    compilerConfiguration.scriptBaseClass = DelegatingScript.class.name

    def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), compilerConfiguration)

    Script script = shell.parse("""
    delegate.query() {
        ${dsl}
    }
    """)
    script.setDelegate queryBuilder
    script.run()
 }
}
```

This works just fine so long as I do not have the propertyMissing Method defined.  If I do define it, it gets called for some reason and this is the error I see:

```
at com.xxx.xxx.site.dsl.QueryBuilder.propertyMissing(QueryBuilder.groovy:26)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:778)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1731)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3458)
at groovy.util.DelegatingScript.getProperty(DelegatingScript.java:102)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
at Script1$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
```

Just for completeness here is the test case.

```
@Test
 void testEvaluateDsl() {
    DslEvaluator dslEvaluator = new DslEvaluator()
    dslEvaluator.evaluateDsl("""
 match {
    obj {
        //more stuff in here
    }
 }
 """)
}
```

So how can I handle adding the propertyMissing() method without losing my ability to build and execute it as a script at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can answer my own question at this point.

After looking at things a little closer, I noticed a few things.

1. FactoryBuilderSupport extends Binding.  So to bind extra variables to the script I simply need to call setVariable() on my builder instance.  I can get access to the bound variable through the getVariable() method in any of the AbstractFactory methods as they all are provided with an instance of the builder.
2. I was trying to figure out how to set the resolve strategy on the builder so I did not need delegate.query in my dsl.  This was the wrong approach. The FactoryBuilderSupport takes the script in its build method, and handles all of this for me.  Once doing things this way it also fixed the issue of not being able to provide the propertyMissing() method.  The builder also will call run on the provided script.

At the end of the day this is what I have now.

```
def evaluateDsl (dsl) {
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder()
    def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, queryBuilder)

    Script script = shell.parse("""
    query() {
        ${dsl}
    }
    """)
    Query query = queryBuilder.build(script)
    query.toQueryString()
}
```